# Why does score always return zero

Tags: python

Ive tried looking at this problem at Stack Overflow but it didn't really answer my question and Im looking for a specific reason that I can't find to this problem.

Im trying to make a random questions generator that asks 10 random maths questions and then it should give a score out of 10. However it always returns the score as zero and I cant find out why. Please help!

```
import random

count=0
score=0
name=input('Enter your name: ')
print(name+' Welcome to this short test. Please enter a number for       every question')

while count<10:
    numb1=random.randint(1,12)
    numb2=random.randint(1,12)
    numb1Str=str(numb1)
    numb2Str=str(numb2)
    ops=[' add ',' times ',' takeaway ']
    ops2=random.choice(ops)
    question=numb1Str+''.join(ops2)+numb2Str
    print(question)
    ans=int(input('Answer: '))
    if question==numb1+numb2 and ans== numb1+numb2:
        score=score+1
    if question==numb1-numb2 and ans== numb1-numb2:
        score=score+1
    if question==numb1*numb2 and ans== numb1*numb2:
        score=score+1
   count=count+1



print('Your score was: '+str(score))
```

Comment: `question` is a string and will never be equal to a number.

Comment: You can do `print('Your score was: {}'.format(score))` to avoid string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` conditions do not make sense. `question` is a string, not a number.

The important thing is contained in the `ops2` variable. It refers to what operation you are expecting the user to do. So you can change the conditional code to this:

```
if ops2==" add " and ans== numb1+numb2:
    score=score+1
elif ops2==" takeaway " and ans== numb1-numb2:
    score=score+1
elif ops2==" times " and ans== numb1*numb2:
    score=score+1
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense everybody else put pretty much the same thing but I understand why it wasn't working now. Thanks!

Comment: Read through the other answers, aside from readability i don't see the need of checking the operation and the ans, afterall `x + y` will never equal `x - y` or `x * y`

Answer (score 1):

you're supposed to be comparing ans not question

so your code should look like this

```
import random

count=0
score=0
name=input('Enter your name: ')
print(name+' Welcome to this short test. Please enter a number for       every question')

while count< 3:
    numb1=random.randint(1,12)
    numb2=random.randint(1,12)
    numb1Str=str(numb1)
    numb2Str=str(numb2)
    ops=[' add ',' times ',' takeaway ']
    ops2=random.choice(ops)
    question=numb1Str+''.join(ops2)+numb2Str
    print(question)
    ans=int(input('Answer: '))
    if ans==numb1+numb2:
        score=score+1
    if ans==numb1-numb2:
        score=score+1
    if ans==numb1*numb2:
        score=score+1

    count=count+1



print('Your score was: '+str(score))
```

i had to reduce the loop to 3